# No results when execute an autocomplete with jquery

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I try to execute an autocomplete with jQuery but can't see any results.
I have this input text and jquery on index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-8">
  <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control rounded-0" required="required" name="inputnama" placeholder="Search...">
</div>

<script src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/typeahead.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get('search.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my ***search.php*** contains this:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_NAME', 'countries');

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=3306;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));     
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['country'];
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Why I didn't see any results? and If i check the logs didn't see anything. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your javascript in the head of your page or at the bottom of your page?

Comment: sorry. At the button. I update the post with all code